# webdrivercss doesn't save screenshots

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I am new to webdriverio and webdrivercss. I need to make a screenshot of the some DOM element. So, I wrote following:

```
// init WebdriverIO
var client = require('webdriverio').remote({desiredCapabilities:{browserName: 'firefox'}});
// init WebdriverCSS
require('webdrivercss').init(client);
client
    .init()
    .url('http://webdriver.io/')
    .webdrivercss('startpage',[
        {
            name: 'header',
            elem: '.mainnav'
        }
    ], function(err, res) {
            console.log(err, res);
    })
    .end();
```

As a result I got just empty ./webdrivercss directory and 'err', 'res' callback params as 'undefined' values.

Node version 'v0.12.7'.

Comment: pleas close issue, I just found that webdrivercss doesn't support webdriver v3.0.0 and higher.

Answer (score 1):

I also was dealing with this issue earlier. Turns out that *WebdriverCSS* isn't compatible with the latest version of *WebdriverIO*.

> **@christian-bromann** commented on Jul 9
>
> Hi **@terekim**, I am currently working on updating *WebdriverCSS* so it works with *WebdriverIO* v3. Currently it does not work. Please stay tuned.
>
> https://github.com/webdriverio/webdrivercss/issues/89

The latest sub-`v3` version of *WebdriverCSS* is `2.4.5`.

Answer (score -1):

if you need to create screenshot of some specific element you need to

1. create screenshot of browser
2. get size and location on the page and cut from screenchot taken in step 1;

code for c#:

```
public Bitmap getElementImg(Point point, Size size)
    {
        Screenshot myScreenShot = ((ITakesScreenshot)Instance).GetScreenshot();

        Bitmap screen = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(myScreenShot.AsByteArray));

        Bitmap eleScreenshot = screen.Clone(new Rectangle(point, size), screen.PixelFormat);

        return eleScreenshot;
    }
```

Point point, Size size -- elements size and location